# SQL Count: How to count value of a column from the same value of other column

Tags: sql, count, pivot

Sorry about the title.

Sample:
I have this table(tblTry):

```
id | Name | Color
____________________
1  | XYZ  | Black
2  | XYZ  | Black
3  | ASD  | Red
4  | ASD  | White
5  | ASD  | White
```

And this is the output I want:

```
Name | Black | Red | White
__________________________
XYZ  | 2     |  0  |  0
ASD  | 0     |  1  |  2
```

I have this sql but it gives me different output:

```
select distinct
Name,
(select count(*) from tblTry where Color= 'Black') as Black,
(select count(*) from tblTry where Color= 'Red') as Red,
(select count(*) from tblTry where Color= 'White') as White,
from tblTry
group by Name
```

sql above output:

```
__________________________
Name | Black | Red | White
__________________________
XYZ  | 2     |  1  |  2
ASD  | 2     |  1  |  2
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pivot, which has several solutions.  One that is general across databases is to use conditional aggregation:

```
select name,
       sum(case when Color = 'Black' then 1 else 0 end) as Black,
       sum(case when Color = 'Red' then 1 else 0 end) as Red,
       sum(case when Color = 'White' then 1 else 0 end) as White
from tblTry
group by name;
```

The problem with your query is that the counts need to be correlated to each row.  You would do this with an additional `where` condition:

```
(select count(*) from tblTry t2 where t2.Color= 'Black' and t2.name = tblTry.name) as Black,
```